Flutter: Show Google Bottomsheet for Phone number selection
In flutter I want to display Google's default phone number picker bottomsheet rather than making a custom one to let users select their phone number from sim cards. See the below image for reference. Is there any package or inbuilt method that I can use to achieve this functionality?


At first, I implemented it using method channels with the help of this documentation - "https://developers.google.com/identity/phone-number-hint/android"
and then I created my plugin but then I searched it on pub.dev
and it's already created by someone.
"https://pub.dev/packages/phone_number_hint"

can you please share the source code or any github link here? I checked this  [phone_number_hint] is not working

it's working in a real device. You can go to the github link of this package to access the source code. And, any error you are getting on the console?
